# WiX RemoveFolderEx not working?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I wanted WiX to remove the AppData folder when uninstalling, so I looked at RemoveFolderEx and followed a few posts/guides on how to get it working.  As far as i can tell, my implementation should work, but it does not.  I'm using the following:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="PRIVATEDATAFOLDER" Name="MyApp"/>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
<Property Id="PRIVATEDATAFOLDER">
    <RegistrySearch Root="HKCU" Key="Software\AppCo\MyApp" Type="raw" 
                    Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER_REGSEARCH" Name="PrivateDir" />
</Property>
<DirectoryRef Id='PRIVATEDATAFOLDER'>
    <Component Id="PrivateData" Guid="myGuid">
        <CreateFolder Directory="PRIVATEDATAFOLDER"/>
        <util:RemoveFolderEx Property="PRIVATEDATAFOLDER" On="uninstall"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="PRIVATEDATAFOLDER" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\AppCo\MyApp" Name="PrivateDir" 
                       Type="string" Value="[PRIVATEDATAFOLDER]" KeyPath="yes"/>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:
After checking a verbose log I get the error:

WixRemoveFoldersEx:  **Error 0x80070057**: Missing folder property: PRIVATEDATAFOLDER

Comment: This might help you: http://www.hass.de/content/wix-how-use-removefolderex-your-xml-scripts

Comment: I followed that guide exactly, but I am receiving the above issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your logs, above the '**Error 0x80070057**: Missing folder property: PRIVATEDATAFOLDER' is there a log line such as 'Ignoring disallowed property PRIVATEDATAFOLDER' and if so, have you tried adding **'secure="yes"'** to your PRIVATEDATAFOLDER property?

Comment: This adds the property to the **[SecureCustomProperties](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/SetRestrictedPublicProp.htm)** list of properties that can be passed from the user interface's client process (run with user rights), to the server process (running with LocalSystem rights) during the installation. The server process runs the actual installation and can not receive the property values set in the user interface, unless the property is marked as secure via the SecureCustomProperties list of properties when the setup is run in a locked down desktop environment.

Comment: Also see the **[Property element description](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/property.html)**. It is perhaps a better explanation. Major upgrades often fail because the ActionProperty property item of the [Upgrade table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372379(v=vs.85).aspx) isn't in the SecureCustomProperties list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different Id for the Property than the Directory. They're clashing, which causes the property to be empty when RemovedFoldersEx tries to process it.

Comment: Tried this, but still no dice.  The logs: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding APPFOLDER property. Its value is 'C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\AppCo\'.  
Then a little further down: WixRemoveFoldersEx:  Error 0x80070057: Missing folder property: APPFOLDER

I changed the directory to 'PrivateDataFolder' and the Property to APPFOLDER, but still RemoveFolderEx doesnt want to work.

Comment: Please post a complete log somewhere and provide a link.

Comment: **[How to create a verbose MSI log file](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm)**.