# Using a condition to make changes to the Windows firewall in WIX

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to make changes to the Windows firewall based on a property that is set in a dialog. I can see in the log that the property is being set correctly but the firewall rules are being created regardless of the value of the property.

My code is...

```xml
<Component Id="ChangeFirewall" Guid="*" KeyPath="yes">
   <Condition><![CDATA[ChgFirewall = "True"]]></Condition>
     <fire:FirewallException Id="FW6501" Name="6501" Port="6501" 
                                         Protocol="tcp" Scope="any"/>
     <fire:FirewallException Id="FW6502" Name="6502" Port="6502" 
                                         Protocol="tcp" Scope="any"/>
     <fire:FirewallException Id="FW6505" Name="6505" Port="6505" 
                                         Protocol="tcp" Scope="any"/>
</Component>
```

If ChgFirewall is False why does the firewall get changed?

**Update:** I have added the code for the dialog that sets the CHGFIREWALL property...

```
<Dialog Id="FirewallDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="yes">
    <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="20" Y="20" Width="280" Height="40" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
      <Text>This program uses TCP ports 6501, 6501, and 6505 for coordinating information between workstations. These ports must be unblocked for it to work correctly</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Instructions" Type="Text" X="20" Y="70" Width="280" Height="30" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
      <Text>This installer can attempt to automatically modify the Windows Firewall for you, or you may manually modify the firewall settings.</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="CHGFIREWALL" Id="CHGFIREWALL" Width="340" Height="44" X="20" Y="120">
      <RadioButtonGroup Property="CHGFIREWALL">
        <RadioButton Text="Have the installer update the firewwall settings for Guru (Recommended)" Height="13" Value="True" Width="340" X="0" Y="0" />
        <RadioButton Text="Manually update the firewall settings" Height="13" Value="False" Width="340" X="0" Y="15" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"></Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="CancelButton" Type="PushButton" Text="Cancel" Height="17" Width="56" X="180" Y="243" Cancel="yes">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Exit" />
    </Control>
  </Dialog>
```

Also this is my definition of the property...

```
<Property Id='CHGFIREWALL' Value='False' Secure='yes'/>
```

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved?

Comment: No, I have not been able to resolve the problem yet

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, UPPERCASE the property and set the attribute 'secure="yes". This ensures that the property is passed properly to the server process as [explained in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25084666/129130).

Then the issue is how you set the property? Is is set by a custom action, or do you set it in the Property table or on the command line?

Comment: The property is set using a custom dialog. I have added the code to the original question.

Comment: Open the compiled MSI with Orca, verify that the condition field for the component looks like expected. And also try to change this field on the fly to test different conditons - then do a test run.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the value on the fly. I did download a version of Orca and as far as I can tell the property looks correct. The dialog had the property (CHGFIREWALL) for Control First (s50).

Comment: The condition field is CHGFIREWALL = "True", so that looks correct